# select a column in foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Suppose I have two tables in SQL where 
table1 has columns - id, name, sex.
table2 has columns - eid, group, hours.
column 'eid' is the  foreign key in table2 and column 'id' is the primary key on table1.

suppose I conduct a search using 'select * from table2 where hour=x' in table 2 and get some results. How can I list the names of the people (from table1) associated with the ids from the search?

GOt it!

Comment: Make an inner join from table2 to table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.NAME FROM TABLE2 T2
   INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON (T1.ID=T2.EID)
    WHERE T2.HOUR=X
```